# Monitor WCF service memory usage

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, memory

Good day,

Is there a way to monitor the memory usage of a WCF service?

I Googled and couldn't find any proper answer. Unfortunately I don't have access to 3rd party tools like RedGate ANTS or the JetBrains memory profiler.

I have enabled all performance counters in my service web config in order to see if I can use the Performance Monitor to view the memory usage but I don't know where to look to get the amount of memory being used by the service.

I also created a load test for one of the wcf methods just as a test to see if it can tell me how much memory was used by the service during the test, but also don't think it gives me the info I need.

Does anyone know how I could do this or point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Performance counters are watched with help of PerfMon.exe

Comment: I did open up the Performance Monitor tool but not sure which counter I need to add to see memory usage of that specific web service only. Ideally after the load test is run, let's say for 15-20 minutes, I want to see the memory usage peak for that period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to watch Performance counters by standart means you should use PerfMon utilite. Launch it from cmd and open **System monitor** link. There you should add new monitor (*CTRL+N*). Depending on the CLR version and hosting paramenters of your service you can select two options from the appeared list, which could probably help you:

1) **ServiceModelServices (3.0 or 4.0)** - monitors the information about your services, number of instances, processor loading, transactions, security, numbers of calls and so on.

2) **Memory in CLR. NET** - helps you to monitor the memory usage by .NET FrameWork applications. There you should choose your service hosting process (w3wp for IIS for example). After this you can watch the required infromation.

Comment: What is `ServiceModelServices` and where it can be downloaded from?